# Haskell: List combination for Integers

Tags: haskell

I have a given list, e.g. `[2, 3, 5, 587]` and I want to have a complete list of the combination. So want something like `[2, 2*3,2*5, 2*587, 3, 3*5, 3*587, 5, 5*587, 587]`. Since I am on beginner level with Haskell I am curious how a list manipulation would look like.

Additionally I am curious if the computation of the base list might be expensive how would this influence the costs of the function? (**If** I would assume the list has limit values, i.e < 20)

Rem.: The order of the list could be done afterwards, but I have really no clue if this is cheaper within the function or afterwards.

Comment: Permutations would mean all the list elements but shuffled in different orders. Are you sure you don't mean "combinations"? Also, why are you getting only groups of 1 or two elements and not groups of 3 or 4?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, no permutation, more a combination. You are also right, that the groups of 3 combination is of interest, although not mentioned explicitly. But I guess, depending on the suggestions this should be a minor step to adapt it finally. Anyway, your questions/doubts gave me a little re-think of 'What do I wanna achieve?'. Thx.

Comment: [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265454/subsequences-of-length-n-from-list-performance/21268310) contains a good discussion on generating combinations in Haskell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems what you want is all pairs of products from the list:

```
ghci> :m +Data.List
ghci> [ a * b | a:bs <- tails [2, 3, 5, 587], b <- bs ]
[6,10,1174,15,1761,2935]
```

But you also want the inital numbers:

```
ghci> [ a * b | a:bs <- tails [2, 3, 5, 587], b <- 1:bs ]
[2,6,10,1174,3,15,1761,5,2935,587]
```

This uses a list comprehension, but this could also be done with regular list operations:

```
ghci> concatMap (\a:bs -> a : map (a*) bs) . init $ tails [2, 3, 5, 587]
[2,6,10,1174,3,15,1761,5,2935,587]
```

The latter is a little easier to explain:

- [`Data.List.tails`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v%3atails) produces all the suffixes of a list:

  ```
  ghci> tails [2, 3, 5, 587]
  [[2,3,5,587],[3,5,587],[5,587],[587],[]]
  ```
- [`Prelude.init`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3ainit) drops the last element from a list.  Here I use it to drop the empty suffix, since processing that causes an error in the next step.

  ```
  ghci> init [[2,3,5,587],[3,5,587],[5,587],[587],[]]
  [[2,3,5,587],[3,5,587],[5,587],[587]]

  ghci> init $ tails [2, 3, 5, 587]
  [[2,3,5,587],[3,5,587],[5,587],[587]]
  ```
- [`Prelude.concatMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3aconcatMap) runs a function over each element of a list, and combines the results into a flattened list.  So

  ```
  ghci> concatMap (\a -> replicate a a) [1,2,3]
  [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
  ```
- `\(a:bs) -> a : map (a*) bs` does a couple things.

  1. I pattern match on my argument, asserting that it matches an list with at least one element (which is why I dropped the empty list with `init`) and stuffs the initial element into `a` and the later elements into `bs`.
  2. This produces a list that has the same first element as the argument `a:`, but
  3. Multiplies each of the later elements by `a` (`map (a*) bs`).

Comment: the OP later clarified in the comments that they want all the combinations, not just pairs. This is probably intended to produce all the divisors of a number from its prime factorization. :)

Comment: right about the intention - good guess, but the given approach is wrong ;) e.g. 2*2*587 wouldn't lead to the divisor 4 (!) But the given solution is fine for list manipulation - which was one of my objective to see how it might work.

Answer (score 6):

The others have explained how to make pairs, so I concern myself here with getting the combinations.

If you want the combinations of *all* lengths, that's just the [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of your list, and can be computed the following way:

```
powerset :: [a] -> [[a]]
powerset (x:xs) = let xs' = powerset xs in xs' ++ map (x:) xs'
powerset []     = [[]]

-- powerset [1, 2] === [[],[2],[1],[1,2]]
-- you can take the products:
-- map product $ powerset [1, 2] == [1, 2, 1, 2]
```

There's an alternative `powerset` implementation in Haskell that's considered sort of a classic:

```
import Control.Monad

powerset = filterM (const [True, False])
```

You could look at the [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/Control-Monad.html#filterM) of `filterM` to see how it works essentially the same way as the other `powerset` above.

On the other hand, if you'd like to have all the combinations of a certain size, you could do the following:

```
combsOf :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
combsOf n _ | n < 1 = [[]]
combsOf n (x:xs)    = combsOf n xs ++ map (x:) (combsOf (n - 1) xs)
combsOf _ _         = []

-- combsOf 2 [1, 2, 3] === [[2,3],[1,3],[1,2]]
```

Comment: +1. the last one also reminiscent of SICP's "make-change". :) --- a related problem, though it wasn't asked: if repetitions are allowed in (ordered) input, produce all unique combinations.

Comment: @WillNess: I also recall the coin change problem fondly; [here's](https://gist.github.com/AndrasKovacs/8686121) a pretty and fast solution that I worked out quite a while ago, if you're interested:)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the suffixes of a list using `Data.List.tails`.
This gives you a list of lists, you can then do the inner multiplications you want on this list with a function like:

```
prodAll [] = []
prodAll (h:t) = h:(map (* h) $ t)
```

You can then map this function over each inner list and concatenate the results:

```
f :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
f = concat . map prodAll . tails
```