# get all possible combinations of k elements from a list

Tags: haskell, combinatorics

I need a function that does the same thing as [`itertools.combinations(iterable, r)` in python](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

So far I came up with this:

```
{-| forward application -}
x -: f = f x
infixl 0 -:

{-| combinations 2 "ABCD" = ["AB","AC","AD","BC","BD","CD"] -}
combinations :: Ord a => Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
combinations k l = (sequence . replicate k) l -: map sort -: sort -: nub
    -: filter (\l -> (length . nub) l == length l)
```

Is there a more elegant and efficient solution?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8626006/98117).

Comment: check https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%26

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Based on @JoseJuan's answer)

You can also use a list comprehension to filter out those where the second character is not strictly smaller than the first:

```
[x| x <- mapM (const "ABCD") [1..2], head x < head (tail x) ]
```

Comment: `head (tail x)` might be cleaner as `x !! 1` no?

Comment: @jozefg I think it's a matter of personal preference - you could even write x !! 0 < x !! 1. For me, coming from an imperative background, using x !! 1 implies that it's a O(1) operation, whereas for Haskell lists, it's O(n). head (tail x), on the other hand, clearly tells me that I'm performing two operations on a linked list.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but that only works with length 2 strings.

Answer (score 12):

`xs` elements taken `n` by `n` is

```
mapM (const xs) [1..n]
```

**all** combinations (n = 1, 2, ...) is

```
allCombs xs = [1..] >>= \n -> mapM (const xs) [1..n]
```

if you need without repetition

```
filter ((n==).length.nub)
```

then

```
combinationsWRep xs n = filter ((n==).length.nub) $ mapM (const xs) [1..n]
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I am looking for. `mapM (const "ABCD") [1..2]` returns `["AA","AB","AC","AD","BA","BB","BC","BD","CA","CB","CC","CD","DA","DB","DC","DD"]` not `["AB","AC","AD","BC","BD","CD"]`

Comment: `filter ((2==).length.nub) $ mapM (const "ABCD") [1..2]` gives `["AB","AC","AD","BA","BC","BD","CA","CB","CD","DA","DB","DC"]`. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

(Based on @FrankSchmitt’s answer)

We have `map (const x) [1..n] == replicate n x` so we could change his answer to

```
[x| x <- sequence (replicate 2 "ABCD"), head x < head (tail x) ]
```

And while in original question, `2` was a parameter `k`, for this particular example would probably not want to replicate with 2 and write

```
[ [x1,x2] | x1 <- "ABCD", x2 <- "ABCD", x1 < x2 ]
```

instead.

With a parameter `k` things are a bit more tricky if you want to generate them without duplicates. I’d do it recursively:

```
f 0 _  = [[]]
f _ [] = []
f k as = [ x : xs | (x:as') <- tails as, xs <- f (k-1) as' ]
```

(This variant does not remove duplicates if there are already in the list `as`; if you worry about them, pass `nub as` to it)

Answer (score 3):

This SO answer:

[subsequences of length n from list performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265454/subsequences-of-length-n-from-list-performance/21288092#21288092)

is the fastest solution to the problem that I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

```
compositions :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
compositions k xs
    | k > length xs = []
    | k <= 0        = [[]]
    | otherwise     = csWithoutHead ++ csWithHead
    where   csWithoutHead = compositions k $ tail xs
            csWithHead    = [ head xs : ys | ys <- compositions (k - 1) $ tail xs ]
```