# All the subsets of size N which satisfy a condition in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, optimization, complexity-theory

I would like to write a function, which takes a list and returns a list of all possible subsets which satisfy given condition.
For example for I want to have all 3-size subsets of [1,2,3,4] but without any subset which contains 2 and 3.

```
$> func [1,2,3,4] 3
[[1,2,4],[1,3,4]]
```

To generate all subsets with size N I have following function (found [here](http://www.csinaction.com/2014/11/12/concise-computation-of-subsets-in-haskell/)):

```
kCombinations :: [a] -> Integer -> [[a]]
kCombinations _      0 = [[]]
kCombinations []     _ =  []
kCombinations (x:xs) k = withHead ++ withoutHead
  where withHead    = map (x:) (kCombinations xs (k-1))
        withoutHead = kCombinations xs k
```

I know that the easiest solution for my problem would be to generate first all combinations and after that to use filter function. But for bigger problems like `kCombinations [1..30] 6` it takes ages to finish.

Could you tell me how could I filter out some data during generation of all combinations?

Comment: Are you asking how to compute O(2^n) values in less than O(2^n) time?

Comment: How is your condition given? Is it a condition that allows to rule out some subsets based on just a few elements of it (as in your example)?

Comment: `30 choose 6` is `593775`, so I would expect it to take a little while if not just to print it out (if you're printing the list). In GHCi, it takes my computer about 2 seconds to compute it and much longer to print it (I didn't wait for it to finish). You might be able to improve it some with a difference list since you're appending often, especially since it looks like a lot of it will associate to the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to improve the `subsequencesOfSize` function, that user5402 mentioned. Compare [this](http://ideone.com/LrpZMh) and [this](http://ideone.com/ZubdHR). This is because of `(l-n)` in the second version, so `subsequencesOfSize 3 [1..350]` is equal to `subsequencesBySize [1..350] !! 347`, so a lot of unused lists are created.

When filtering subsequences by a predicate `p` which has the property that `p xs` is true implies `all p (inits xs)` is true, it is possible to integrate the predicate into the generation of subsequences for even greater efficiency. Such is the case for the predicate "not containing 2 and 3".

And here is what you want:

```
zapWith f    xs     []  = xs
zapWith f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : zapWith f xs ys

filterCombs :: ([a] -> Bool) -> Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
filterCombs p n xs | n > length xs = [] 
filterCombs p n xs = go xs id !! n where
    go    []  ds = [[[]]]
    go (x:xs) ds
        | p (ds' []) = zapWith (++) ([] : map (map (x:)) with) without
        | otherwise  = without
        where
            ds'     = ds . (x:)
            with    = go xs ds'
            without = go xs ds
```

`zapWith` is intentionally non-exhaustive. `ds` in the `go` function is a difference list, that contains all previous elements. You can read `go` like this: if a property `p` holds for `<all previous elements of xs> ++ [x]` then include combinations with `x` and without `x`, otherwise include only without `x`.

Some examples:

```
conseq (x:y:xs) = succ x == y && conseq (y:xs)
conseq      xs  = True

main = do
    print $ filterCombs (\xs -> any (`notElem` xs) [2,3]) 3 [1..5]
    print $ filterCombs conseq 4 $ [1..8] ++ [8,7..1]
    print $ filterCombs (all (<= 10)) 9 [1..5000]
```

prints

```
[[1,2,4],[1,2,5],[1,3,4],[1,3,5],[1,4,5],[2,4,5],[3,4,5]]
[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6],[3,4,5,6],[4,5,6,7],[4,5,6,7],[5,6,7,8],[5,6,7,8]]
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10],[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10],[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10],[1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10],[1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10],[1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]
```

Comment: I added a note about what `filterCombs` expects of the predicate `p` - hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

This question comes up a lot and the most recent comparison of various methods may be found here: [Comparison of techniques for generating combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26727673/haskell-comparison-of-techniques-for-generating-combinations/26727936)

The last method (`subsequencesOfSize`) mentioned is very performant due to memoization. A  timing comparison on my machine with ghci:

```
length $ kCombinations [1..30] 6        - time: 2.73 secs
length $ subsequencesOfSize 6 [1..30]   - time: 0.40 secs
```

To solve your original problem (subsets without both 2 and 3), there are basically two ways to compute the answer:

```
  -- import Data.List

  answer1 = filter (\s -> not (elem 2 s && elem 3 s)) $ subsequencesOfSize 6 [1..30]
  answer2 = map (2:) subs23 ++ map (3:) subs23 ++ subsequencesOfSize 6 nums'
    where nums = [1..30]
          nums' = [1..30] \\ [2,3]
          subs23 = subsequencesOfSize 5 nums'
```

Timings on my box (ghci again):

```
length answer1           -- 1.48 secs
length answer2           -- 0.36 secs
```

`answer1` is clearly the naive approach; `answer2` applies some basic set theory and easily generalizes to counting subsets not containing any two numbers - you can decide whether it's legal or not.