# Function to generate the unique combinations of a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell, combinations, combinatorics

Is there a Haskell function that generates all the unique combinations of a given length from a list?

```
Source = [1,2,3]

uniqueCombos 2 Source = [[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]]
```

I tried looking in Hoogle but could not find a function that did this specifically. Permutations does not give the desired result.

Has anybody used a similar function before?

Comment: Can the original list have any duplicates?

Answer (score 14):

I don't know a predefined function either, but it's pretty easy to write yourself:

```
-- Every set contains a unique empty subset.
subsets 0 _ = [[]]

-- Empty sets don't have any (non-empty) subsets.
subsets _ [] = []

-- Otherwise we're dealing with non-empty subsets of a non-empty set.
-- If the first element of the set is x, we can get subsets of size n by either:
--   - getting subsets of size n-1 of the remaining set xs and adding x to each of them
--     (those are all subsets containing x), or
--   - getting subsets of size n of the remaining set xs
--     (those are all subsets not containing x)
subsets n (x : xs) = map (x :) (subsets (n - 1) xs) ++ subsets n xs
```

Comment: It's interesting to note that if the order of appearance of  `subsets 0 _ = [[]]` and `subsets _ [] = []` changes it breaks.

Answer (score 9):

Using `Data.List`:

```
import Data.List
combinations k ns = filter ((k==).length) $ subsequences ns
```

Reference: [99 Haskell Problems](https://wiki.haskell.org/99_questions/Solutions/26)

There are quite a few interesting solutions in the reference, I just picked a concise one.

Comment: [Pointfree](http://pointfree.io/): `combinations = (. subsequences) . filter . (. length) . (==)`

Comment: The totally point-free one hurts my head. I find `combinations k = filter ((k==).length) . subsequences` a lot more readable.

Comment: Pointfree is really interesting. I'm actively programming in Haskell right now, and am starting to be able to parse these more complex pointfree expressions more easily. A question of being used to them, then, I guess, like so many other things...

Answer (score 4):

It is not clear to me how concerned you would be about performance.

If it can be of any use, back in 2014, somebody posted some sort of [performance contest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26727673/haskell-comparison-of-techniques-for-generating-combinations) of various Haskell combinations generating algorithms.

For combinations of 13 items out of 26, execution times varied from 3 to 167 seconds ! The fastest entry was provided by [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265454/subsequences-of-length-n-from-list-performance/21288092#21288092). Here is the non-obvious (for me at least) source code:

```
subsequencesOfSize :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
subsequencesOfSize n xs = let l = length xs
                          in if (n > l) then []
                             else subsequencesBySize xs !! (l-n)
 where
   subsequencesBySize [] = [[[]]]
   subsequencesBySize (x:xs) = let next = subsequencesBySize xs
                               in zipWith (++)
                                    ([]:next)
                                    ( map (map (x:)) next ++ [[]] )
```

More recently, the question has been [revisited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58262463/filter-subsets-based-on-length), in the specific context of picking a few elements from a large list (5 out of 100). In that case, you cannot use something like `subsequences [1 .. 100]` because that refers to a list whose length is 2<sup>100</sup> ≃ 1.26*10<sup>30</sup>. I submitted a state machine based [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58368298/11282404) which is not as Haskell-idiomatic as I would like, but is reasonably efficient for that sort of situations, something around 30 clock cycles per output item.

### Side note: Using *multisets* to generate combinations ?

Also, there is a [Math.Combinatorics.Multiset](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/multiset-comb) package available. Here is the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/multiset-comb-0.2.4.1/docs/Math-Combinatorics-Multiset.html). I have only briefly tested it, but it can be used to generate combinations.

For example, the set of all combinations of 3 elements out of 8 are just like the "permutations" of a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) with two elements (Present and Absent) with respective multiplicities of 3 and (8-3)=5.

Let us use the idea to generate all combinations of 3 elements out of 8. There are (8*7*6)/(3*2*1) = 336/6 = 56 of them.

```
*L M Mb T MS> import qualified Math.Combinatorics.Multiset as MS
*Math.Combinatorics.Multiset L M Mb T MS> pms = MS.permutations
*Math.Combinatorics.Multiset L M Mb T MS> :set prompt "λ> "
λ> 
λ> pms38 = pms $ MS.fromCounts [(True, 3), (False,5)]
λ> 
λ> length pms38
56
λ>
λ> take 3 pms38
[[True,True,True,False,False,False,False,False],[True,True,False,False,False,False,False,True],[True,True,False,False,False,False,True,False]]
λ> 
λ> str = "ABCDEFGH"
λ> combis38 = L.map fn pms38 where fn mask = L.map fst $ L.filter snd (zip str mask)
λ> 
λ> sort combis38
["ABC","ABD","ABE","ABF","ABG","ABH","ACD","ACE","ACF","ACG","ACH","ADE","ADF","ADG","ADH","AEF","AEG","AEH","AFG","AFH","AGH","BCD","BCE","BCF","BCG","BCH","BDE","BDF","BDG","BDH","BEF","BEG","BEH","BFG","BFH","BGH","CDE","CDF","CDG","CDH","CEF","CEG","CEH","CFG","CFH","CGH","DEF","DEG","DEH","DFG","DFH","DGH","EFG","EFH","EGH","FGH"]
λ>
λ> length combis38
56
λ>
```

So functionally at least, the idea of using multisets to generate combinations works.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such operation in lib, but you can easily implement it yourself:

```
import Data.List

main = putStrLn $ show $ myOp 2 [1, 2, 3]

myOp :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
myOp 0 _ = []
myOp 1 l = map (:[]) l
myOp c l = concat $ map f $ tails l
    where
        f :: [a] -> [[a]]
        f []     = []
        f (x:xs) = map (x:) $ myOp (c - 1) xs
```

Answer (score 2):

@melpomene's answer is generic and very concise. That's probably what you see in many places over the internet where a `combinationsOf` function is required.

However hidden behind the double recursion it does tons of needless recursive calls those can be avoided, yielding a much efficient code. i.e we don't need to make any calls if the length of the list is shorter than `k`.

I would propose a double termination check.

```
combinationsOf :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
combinationsOf k xs = runner n k xs
                      where
                      n = length xs
                      runner :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
                      runner n' k' xs'@(y:ys) = if k' < n'      -- k' < length of the list
                                                then if k' == 1
                                                     then map pure xs'
                                                     else map (y:) (runner (n'-1) (k'-1) ys) ++ runner (n'-1) k' ys
                                                else pure xs'   -- k' == length of the list.

λ> length $ subsets 10 [0..19] -- taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52602906/4543207
184756
(1.32 secs, 615,926,240 bytes)

λ> length $ combinationsOf 10 [0..19]
184756
(0.45 secs, 326,960,528 bytes)
```

So the above code, while optimized as much as possible, is still inefficient mainly due to double recursion from within. As a rule of thumb, in any algorithm a double recursions should best be avoided or be considered under very careful inspection.

The following algorithm on the other hand, is a very efficient way of doing this job both on speed and memory consumption.

```
combinationsOf :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
combinationsOf k as@(x:xs) | k == 1    = map pure as
                           | k == l    = pure as
                           | k >  l    = []
                           | otherwise = run (l-1) (k-1) as $ combinationsOf (k-1) xs
                             where
                             l = length as

                             run :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
                             run n k ys cs | n == k    = map (ys ++) cs
                                           | otherwise = map (q:) cs ++ run (n-1) k qs (drop dc cs)
                                           where
                                           (q:qs) = take (n-k+1) ys
                                           dc     = product [(n-k+1)..(n-1)] `div` product [1..(k-1)]

λ> length $ combinationsOf 10 [0..19]
184756
(0.09 secs, 51,126,448 bytes)
```

Comment: With the second code block in GHCi, `combinationsOf 3 [1 .. 3] == [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3]`, which is incorrect, and `combinationsOf 4 [1 .. 3]` froze my machine, I think due to swapping from memory exhaustion.

Comment: @Chai T. Rex Thank you for heads up. I tried to fix it. However this is not a code for combinations with repetitions so the updated code won't allow `k > l`.

Answer (score 0):

[Monadic solution for unique combinations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v11ulza40rU):

```
cb _ 0 = [[]]
cb xs n = (nxs >>= (\(nx, x) -> (x:) <$> (cb [z | (n,z) <- nxs, n>nx] (n-1)) )) where nxs = zip [1..] xs
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried looking for a solution in the standard library, but couldn't find any. I came up with this:

```hs
genCombinations :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
genCombinations 0 _ = [[]]
genCombinations n xs =
  genCombinations' [] xs n
  where
    -- \| Generates new combinations by replacing elements in the old combinations (the accumulator)
    -- \| with the first element from the list.
    genCombinations' :: [[a]] -> [a] -> Int -> [[a]]
    genCombinations' acc [] _ = acc
    genCombinations' acc (x : xs) n =
      -- replace elements in lists from accumulator, and add a combination made of the first element
      let newCombinations = concatMap (replaceElems x) acc ++ [replicate n x]
       in newCombinations ++ genCombinations' (acc ++ newCombinations) xs n

    replaceElems :: a -> [a] -> [[a]]
    replaceElems x xs =
      replaceElems' x (length xs) 0 xs

    replaceElems' :: a -> Int -> Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
    replaceElems' _ _ _ [] = []
    -- count - how many elements were replaced before
    -- n - total length of the combination
    replaceElems' x n count [y]
      | count == n - 1 = [[y]] -- all prievous elements were replaced, don't replace now
      | count == 0 = [[x]] -- no elements were replaced, replace now
      | otherwise = [[x], [y]]
    replaceElems' x n count (y : ys) =
      -- don't replace the element, don't increment the counter
      map (y :) (replaceElems' x n count ys)
        -- replace the element, increment the counter
        ++ map (x :) (replaceElems' x n (count + 1) ys)
```

Works by keeping a list of all generated combinations in the accumulator. When processing a next element from the input list (`x`), it creates new combinations, by replacing element's of lists in the accumulator with `x` in almost all possible ways. Then it adds a new combination, made of `x`-s only.

When replacing elements from previously generated combinations, it doesn't replace all their elements, or none, so no combination is generated twice.

What's cool is that it is **lazy** with respect to the input list's length, so it can generate all combinations of length n, even from an **infinite list**.