# Convert recursion into list comprehension

Tags: haskell, recursion, list-comprehension

I have this function:

```
subsetsOfThree [] = []
subsetsOfThree [x,y,z] = [[x,y,z]]
subsetsOfThree fls@(x:y:z:xs) = ([x,y,z] : subsetsOfThree (xs))  ++ 
  (subsetsOfThree (x:xs)) ++
  (subsetsOfThree (y:xs)) ++ 
  (subsetsOfThree (z:xs)) ++ 
  (subsetsOfThree (x:y:xs)) ++
  (subsetsOfThree (x:z:xs)) ++ 
  (subsetsOfThree (y:z:xs)) 
subsetsOfThree _ = []
```

And it take only the subsets of length 3, but I cannot get rid of converting it in equivalent list comprehension, I tryed:

```
subsetsOfThree [] = []
subsetsOfThree [x,y,z] = [[x,y,z]]
subsetsOfThree (x:y:z:xs) = [xs6 | xs1 <- subsetsOfThree xs,
 xs2 <- [xs1, (x:xs)],
 xs3 <- [xs2, (y:xs)],
 xs4 <- [xs3, (z:xs)],
 xs5 <- [xs4, (x:y:xs)],
 xs6 <- [xs5, (y:z:xs)]
 ]
subsetsOfThree _ = []
```

But it always returns `[]`

Any clue will be appreciated

Comment: Consider that `subsetsOfThree [1,2,3,4]` makes one recursive call `subsetsOfThree [4]`, which results in `[]`. Since `xs1` is drawing from an empty list, none of the other generators are used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might want to exploit the `tails` helper function:

```
subsetsOfThree ws = [ [x,y,z] | (x:xs) <- tails ws, (y:ys) <- tails xs, z <- ys ]
```

This relies on `(_:_) <- list` generating nothing when `list` is empty, rather than throwing a runtime error.

Comment: You even make my function make sense and work properly, I will quote you in an answer of mine, and give to you a bounty if stack overflow let me

Comment: I add the bounty in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58262463/filter-subsets-based-on-length because I cannot add it in this one, if you answer there you get the bounty for you help, thanks so much

Comment: @DamiánRafaelLattenero Thank you, but don't worry about giving me a bounty. Quoting with credit, as you did, is already enough.

Comment: @chi the bounty is already there. the rep is already spent. :)