# Haskell list monad looping

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, monads

I have a list comprehension that looks like this:

```
cross ps = [  p* pp * ppp | p <- ps, pp <- ps, ppp <- ps, p >= pp , pp >= ppp ]
```

How do I achieve this using monads without literally typing out the list names?

```
dim ps n = do
    p <- ps
    pp <- ps
    ppp <- ps
    p...p <- ps

    guard (p >= pp && pp >= ppp ... && p...p >=p....p)
    return (p*pp*ppp*p...p)
```

How can I do this without explicitly assigning values in order to use the list monad?

Comment: Its not clear what you need to achieve. You say you have a "list of lists", but "cross" takes all the samples from one list "ps". Can you give us an example of the inputs and outputs?

Comment: ps is a list of prime numbers. and the output is the upper triangle of a pxp matrix. I'm trying to increase dimensions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it

```
ascending :: Ord a => [a] -> Bool
ascending list = and $ zipWith (>=) (tail list) list

dim ps n = map product $ filter ascending allComb 
    where allComb = replicateM n ps
```

The `replicateM` comes from `Control.Monad` and for the list monad it generates all combinations of `n` elements of the given list.
Then I filter out just the combinations that are in an ascending order and finally calculate the products of the lists that remained.

Answer (score 4):

A close translation could be:

```
dim :: Num a => [a] -> Int -> [a]
dim ps n = do
  chosen <- replicateM n ps
  guard $ increasing chosen
  return $ product chosen

increasing :: Ord a => [a] -> Bool
increasing []        = True
increasing xs@(_:ys) = and $ zipWith (<=) xs ys
```

However, this could be improved by putting the guards earlier. I mean:

```
[ ... | p1<-xs, p2<-xs, p3<-xs, p1 <= p2, p2 <= p3 ]
```

is worse than

```
[ ... | p1<-xs, p2<-xs, p1 <= p2, p3<-xs, p2 <= p3 ]
```

since the latter will avoid scanning the whole list for `p3<-xs` when `p1 <= p2`, so we are not going to generate anything anyway.

So, let's try again, with a more primitive approach:

```
dim :: Num a => [a] -> Int -> [a]
dim ps 0 = [1]
dim ps n = do
   x  <- ps
   xs <- dim (filter (>=x) ps) (n-1)
   return (x * xs)
```

Now we discard impossible alternatives early, removing them from `ps` before the recursive call.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the easiest to understand solution is to “literally use a loop”:

```
dim ps n = do
    pz <- forM [1..n] $ \_i -> do
       p <- ps
       return p

    guard $ descending pz
    return $ product pz
```

But `do {p <- ps; return p}` is [equivalent to simply `ps`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad_laws), and for `forM [1..n] $ \_i -> ps` we have the shorthand `replicateM n ps`. So you get to chi's suggested solution. I'd say Luka Horvat's is actually a little better, though.

But then again, as chi remarked, you can make this a lot more efficient by not selecting *all* possible combinations and throwing the vast majority away, but rather only selecting the descending possibilities in the first place. For this I'd manually write a recursive function:

```
descendingChoices :: Ord a => Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
descendingChoices 1 ps = [[p] | p<-ps]  -- aka `pure<$>ps`
descendingChoices n ps = [ p : qs | qs <- descendingChoices (n-1) ps
                                  , p <- ps
                                  , all (<=p) qs
                         ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Given that your list of primes is in ascending order, you can avoid the guards entirely, by only generating each set of products once to begin with:

```
cross :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
cross 0 _ = [[]]
cross n [] = []
cross n all@(x:xs) = ((x:) <$> cross (n - 1) all) ++ cross n xs

dim :: Num a => Int -> [a] -> [a]
dim n xs = map product $ cross n xs
```

Answer (score 1):

If the list of primes is not in ascending order, then the best option is to sort it and use an algorithm that assumes the list is sorted. **amalloy** gave one, however you can make the function that generates k-combinations with repetitions (aka `cross`) quite more efficient by using sharing ([an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21288092/3237465)).

Another such algorithm is

```
dim :: (Num a, Ord a) => Int -> [a] -> [a]
dim 0 xs = [1]
dim n xs = [y * x | x <- xs, y <- dim (n - 1) (takeWhile (<= x) xs)]
```

Note the `takeWhile` instead of `filter`. This way you don't need to process the whole list of primes over and over again, instead you always process only those primes that you actually need.